# Simplifying Function for handling data

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, simplify

I wrote this function to handle certain days with no data in my table but I feel as though having an abundance of `if` statements is not the best way for this to work, nor is it elegant. This code works perfectly I'm just having trouble figuring out a more simple way of doing. Here is my code:

```
    var daysArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    var monday_bool = true;
    var tuesday_bool = true;
    var wednesday_bool = true;
    var thursday_bool = true;
    var friday_bool = true;
    var saturday_bool = true;
    var default_array = [];

    //Build array of day #'s based upon selection
    for (var p = 0; p < data.days.length; p++) {
        default_array.push(data.days[p].day_of_week_Number);
    }

    //Specific handling for days with no data (either in database or "blackout")
    if (data.days.length != daysArray.length) {

        for (z = 0; z < data.days.length; z++) {
            var not_default_start_time = data.days[z].default_start_time;
            var not_default_end_time = data.days[z].default_end_time;
            var not_select_start_time = data.days[z].start_time;
            var not_select_end_time = data.days[z].end_time;
            var not_time_chunk = data.days[z].time_chunk_id;

            if ($.inArray(2, default_array) != 0 && monday_bool == true) {
                not_select_start_time = 0;
                not_select_end_time = 0;
                $("#mondayDate").html("----");
                $("#mondayStart").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_start_time));
                $("#mondayEndTime").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_end_time));
                $("#mondayTimeChunkID").val(not_time_chunk);
                if (data.days[z].comment != null) {
                    var notsubMonday = data.days[z].comment.substring(0, 10);
                    $("#mondayCommentLink").html(notsubMonday + "...");
                }
                monday_bool = false;
            }

            if ($.inArray(3, default_array) != 0 && tuesday_bool == true) {
                not_select_start_time = 0;
                not_select_end_time = 0;
                $("#tuesdayDate").html("----");
                $("#tuesdayStart").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_start_time));
                $("#tuesdayEndTime").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_end_time));
                $("#tuesdayTimeChunkID").val(not_time_chunk);
                if (data.days[z].comment != null) {
                    var notsubTuesday = data.days[z].comment.substring(0, 10);
                    $("#tuesdayCommentLink").html(notsubTuesday + "...");
                }
                tuesday_bool = false;
            }

            if ($.inArray(4, daysArray) != 0 && wednesday_bool == true) {
                not_select_start_time = 0;
                not_select_end_time = 0;
                $("#wednesdayDate").html("----");
                $("#wednesdayStart").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_start_time));
                $("#wednesdayEndTime").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_end_time));
                $("#wednesdayTimeChunkID").val(not_time_chunk);
                if (data.days[z].comment != null) {
                    var notsubWednesday = data.days[z].comment.substring(0, 10);
                    $("#wednesdayCommentLink").html(notsubWednesday + "...");
                }
                wednesday_bool = false;
            }

            if ($.inArray(5, daysArray) != 0 && thursday_bool == true) {
                not_select_start_time = 0;
                not_select_end_time = 0;
                $("#thursdayDate").html("----");
                $("#thursdayStart").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_start_time));
                $("#thursdayEndTime").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_end_time));
                $("#thursdayTimeChunkID").val(not_time_chunk);
                if (data.days[z].comment != null) {
                    var notsubThursday = data.days[z].comment.substring(0, 10);
                    $("#thursdayCommentLink").html(notsubThursday + "...");
                }
                thursday_bool = false;
            }

            if ($.inArray(6, daysArray) != 0 && friday_bool == true) {
                not_select_start_time = 0;
                not_select_end_time = 0;
                $("#fridayDate").html("----");
                $("#fridayStart").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_start_time));
                $("#fridayEndTime").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_end_time));
                $("#fridayTimeChunkID").val(not_time_chunk);
                if (data.days[z].comment != null) {
                    var notsubFriday = data.days[z].comment.substring(0, 10);
                    $("#fridayCommentLink").html(notsubFriday + "...");
                }
                friday_bool = false;
            }

            if ($.inArray(7, daysArray) != 0 && saturday_bool == true) {
                not_select_start_time = 0;
                not_select_end_time = 0;
                $("#saturdayDate").html("----");
                $("#saturdayStart").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_start_time));
                $("#saturdayEndTime").html(buid(not_default_start_time, not_default_end_time, not_select_end_time));
                $("#saturdayTimeChunkID").val(not_time_chunk);
                if (data.days[z].comment != null) {
                    var notsubSaturday = data.days[z].comment.substring(0, 10);
                    $("#saturdayCommentLink").html(notsubSaturday + "...");
                }
                saturday_bool = false;
            }


        }
    }
```

Is there a better way I can go about handling this data and populating the correct fields when data is passed into it instead of using an multitude of `id` statements?

Comment: First try to use `switch case` instead of if.

Comment: All those id's like `$("#fridayDate").` feel like they should be classes in the markup and then indexed like: `$(".daysDate").eq(indexer).` where indexer would be the index (6) of that array of elements with that class.